# Cannot display image added from backend to the site

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a dynamic site in php in which the gallery images are added from the backend. Images uploaded are going to the 'uploads' folder. But I cannot display it on my main page.

This is my code for adding image from the backend

```html
<?php                    
                   
require_once("config/connection.php");



$imgtitle="";
//$discription="";
$file_ext="";
$file_name="";
if(isset($_POST['btnadd']))
{
$proname=$_POST['titlename'];
  




      $file_name = $_FILES['txtfile']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['txtfile']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['txtfile']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['txtfile']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['txtfile']['name'])));
   
 
 $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().".".$file_ext;
      
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        echo "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG or GIF file.";
      }
      
      else if($file_size > 2097152){
         echo 'File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }
      
      else if(empty($errors)==true){
    $rand_name = md5(time());
   $rand_name= rand(0,999999999);
    $source=$_FILES['txtfile']['tmp_name'];
         $destination="../uploads/".$imagename;
   move_uploaded_file($source,$destination);
         
         
      }
      else{
         print_r($errors);
     }
  




         $query1="insert into products_tb(proimg,proname)values('{$destination}','{$proname}')";

         $result=mysql_query($query1,$connection) or die(mysql_error()) ;
          if($result>0)
             {
            echo "<p style='color:green'>Image added Successfully</p>";
             }
    
    
   
 
 }
   



?>
   
        
                  <form action="" name="" class=" form-group" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    
                     <table class="">
                    <tr>
                      <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="titlename" id="titlename" required placeholder="Please enter Title Name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><label for="img_upload">Image Upload</label></td>
                      <td>
                      <input type="file" name="txtfile" id="txtfile" required/>
                       <!--<input type="file" name="image" id="image"/>
-->                      </td>
                    
                    </tr>
                       
                     
                       
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>
                      <input name="btnadd" id="btnadd" class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                   
                  </form>
```

This is my table: [image: products_tb]
This is the code for display gallery images in my home page:

```html
<div style="background-color:#e9ca76" class="gallery-w3layouts" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <h5 style="font-family: 'Crafty Girls';" class="title-w3">Gallery</h5>
      <div class="fancybox" align="center">
              <?php                    
                   
require_once("admin/config/connection.php");
;
$proname="";

$query1="select * from products_tb";
$resource1=mysql_query($query1,$connection);
$result1="";

$id="";
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($resource1))
{
 
  
           $pid=$record['pid'];
     $img="uploads/".$record['proimg'];
     $proname=$record['proname'];
     
           //$proitems=$record['proitem'];
         $result1.="<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 mrgn_less prd'>

                    <img class='fancybox'   src='$img' '><br>
                            
       
                      </div>";
}


?>
 <div class="carousel-inner ">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="container-fluid  mrgn_less">
                    <div class="row"> 
                      
                       <div class="col-md-12  mrgn_less col_bg ">
                       
                          <?php  echo $result1;?>
                          
                       </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div> 
     
</div>
</div>
  
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is what i am getting in my main page:[image: gallery page]

Comment: Check the console for error.

Comment: You already insert folder name with image in table then why you are append folder name while display image on home page?

Comment: Can you show the image path using console that display on home page.

Comment: Check your resulting HTML for errors. There is an apostrophe too many in `<img class='fancybox'   src='$img' '>`.

Comment: @MrLister The string itself wrapped inside double quotes. Maybe the image location is wrong.